# When did Scotty give the captain more power?

Tags: star-trek

I'm reading a [text on thyroid function](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XnWbDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=%22Captain%20Kirk%20always%20called%20on%20Scotty%20for%20more%20power%22&source=bl&ots=Grc13sjvqB&sig=ACfU3U3e75NOoZtJxo7zcPfCS1v0Z2Puzg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1nO3u9P3tAhVPExoKHegfBisQ6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22Captain%20Kirk%20always%20called%20on%20Scotty%20for%20more%20power%22&f=false), and the author is using an example to explain something;

> Captain Kirk always called on Scotty for more power to get past one
> disaster or another. Sometimes Scotty could deliver.

I was wondering what circumstances required Scotty to give the captain "more power".

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Unfortunately this question is likely to be closed because it's too broad. Star Trek is a large franchise and the crew of the Enterprise deal with several situations that could be classified as "disasters". Facing disasters and resolving them is arguably the entire point of the show so it's kind of hard to answer "what are those disasters", especially in a short way. You can check out the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how this site works and how to ask good questions.

Comment: "Sometimes" Scotty could deliver? _Sometimes?!?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example would be from the TOS episode, *[The Changeling](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Changeling_(episode))*, when Kirk ordered Scott to channel full power to the shields, in order to protect the Enterprise from an energy bolt of (at the time) unknown origin.

> **SULU:** *Captain, shields just snapped on. Something heading in at multiwarp speeds.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Evasive manoeuvres, Mister Sulu.*
>
> **SPOCK:** *An extremely powerful bolt of energy, Captain.*
>
> **KIRK:** *Full power to the shields, Mister Scott.*
>
> **SCOTT:** *Giving them all we got, sir.*
>
> <sub>[TOS: "The Changeling" script](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/37.htm)</sub>